# Decoupling XML parser from classes

Tags: java, android, xml, xsd, decoupling

I'm writing an Android application and I want to provide the ability for the end user to create collections of objects from a class hierarchy with XML.  For example: I'd like the user to be able to provide something like this arbitrary example:

```
<animals>
    <dogs>
        <bulldog name="Frank" />
        <mastif name="George" />
    </dogs>
    <cats>
         <mainecoon name="Alex" age="3" />
    </cats>
</animals>
```

I'd like to validate this user-provided XML against a schema I create, and then create instances of these classes based on the XML.  The question I have is that if I add a subclass.. say reptile, I have to change the implementation for the XML parser as well as the schema to validate the XML.  This seems like bad practice because a change in the class hierarchy mandates a change in other places.  Is there anyway to minimize the impact of adding a type to my Android app with regard to the XML the user can provide and the Schema that validates it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.  Using annotations and a framework like JAXB or Simple will let you serialize/deserialize objects to/from xml.  JAXB can be run on Android which could be a solution. [link](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/)

But JAXB is pretty heavy weight so I'm favoring [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download.php) because it is more lightweight.